# How to mock a class that implements UserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockmvc

I have a Client/Server architecture application with SpringBoot for a University Project.

I'm trying to UnitTest my ManageUserController using JUnit and MockMvc.

I need to test that a method, behind a certain path that is accessible to everyone (POST, "api/v1/user/signup"), will return a successful status code, so I mocked the ManageUserService to return me a newUser when registrate(user) has been called.

ManageUserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService overriding loadUserByUsername from Springboot Security to check if a user is registered, to validate his password and his role.

Problem is that even if it's a path is accessible to everyone, when I run the test, 403 Forbidden is returned. I found the problem is in a certain way the UserDetailsService, because if i remove it everything seem to be working, i'm strugglin with this from yesterday, searching for a solution but i don't know how to work it out.

This is my SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter = new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean());
        customAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/v1/user/login");
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1/user/signup").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilter(customAuthenticationFilter);
        http.addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.exceptionHandling((e) -> e.accessDeniedHandler(new AccessDeniedHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
                response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
                response.setHeader("error", "Autorizzazione fallita");
                response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                response.getWriter().write("{\"message\": \"Non sei autorizzato per questa funzionalità\", \"status\": \"error\"}");
            }
        }));
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

ManageUserController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/user")
public class ManageUserController {

    private ManageUserService service;

    @Autowired
    public ManageUserController(ManageUserService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @PostMapping("signup")
    ResponseEntity<Object> signup(@RequestBody User user) {
        User newUser = null;
        try {
            newUser = service.signup(user);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());
        }
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("utente", newUser);
        return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(HttpStatus.CREATED, "response",
                response);
    }
}
```

ManageUserService

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@Transactional
public class ManageUserServiceImpl implements ManageUserService, UserDetailsService {

    private final UtenteRepository utenteRepository;
    private final RuoloRepository ruoloRepository;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @Override
    public User signup(User user) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid User");
        }
        if (utenteRepository.existsByEmail(user.getEmail())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Email already exists");
        }
        user.setRuolo(ruoloRepository.findByName("TRAINER"));
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        return utenteRepository.save(user);
    }



    /**
     * This method find an user from email
     *
     * @param email email of the user to search for
     * @return UserDetails
     * @throws UsernameNotFoundException
     */
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = utenteRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found in DB");
        }
        Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRuolo().getNome()));

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

}
```

ManageUserControllerTest

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = BackendApplicationTest.class)
@WebMvcTest(ManageUserController.class)
class ManageUserControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ManageUserService gestioneUtenzaService;

    @Test
    void createMockMvc() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(mockMvc);
    }

    @Test
    void signupTest() throws Exception {
        String url = "/api/v1/user/signup";
        Ruolo ruoloPrep = new Role(1L, "TRAINER", null, null);
        String utenteJson = "{\n" +
                "    \"name\": \"Name\",\n" +
                "    \"surname\": \"Surname\",\n" +
                "    \"birth\": \"2000-03-03\",\n" +
                "    \"gender\": \"M\",\n" +
                "    \"email\": \"test@gmail.com\",\n" +
                "    \"password\": \"1234*\",\n" +
                "    \"confirmPassword\": \"1234*\"\n" +
                "}";
        User user = new User(null, "Name", "Surname", "test@gmail.com", "1234", true, LocalDate.parse("2000-03-03"), null,null, "M", null, null, null,null, null, null, null, null, null);
        User newUser = new User(1L, "Name", "Surname", "test@gmail.com", "1234", true, LocalDate.parse("2000-03-03"), null,null, "M", null, null, null,null, null, null, null, null, null);
        when(gestioneUtenzaService.signup(user)).thenReturn(newUser);
        mockMvc.perform(post(url).content(utenteJson).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

Any clue of how i could mock the UserDetailsService too and why i still get 403 even with a path that have a permitAll()?
If i run the server and use Postman to make the request, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a unit test, you should exclude the security part here. You can set up MockMvc with a custom security config, see:

```
RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SecuredControllerSpringBootIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
          .webAppContextSetup(context)
          .apply(springSecurity())
          .build();
    }

    // ... other methods

    @WithMockUser("spring")
    @Test
    public void givenAuthRequestOnPrivateService_shouldSucceedWith200() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/private/hello").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
          .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

For more details: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-integration-tests

Comment: Already saw that tutorial but it keep giving me 403, also, if i annotate with SpringBootTest the class, it will configure the complete application and not only the controller and his dependency, seem that this is the problem.

I've tried with MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(manageUserController) and seem to be working that way